# Google Test generated extra Visual Studio projects

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, googletest

I used [this tutorial](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project) to add google test to my existing CMake project. I use CMake to generate my Visual Studio 2015 project files as well. Unfortunately, doing so also caused CMake/Visual Studio to generate six additional Visual Studio projects which were not there before:

[image]

Is there a way to hide or get rid of these? They are cluttering my workspace...

Comment: This might help: http://blog.audio-tk.com/2015/09/01/sorting-source-files-and-projects-in-folders-with-cmake-and-visual-studioxcode/

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is: don't build gmock and gtest together with your project (I know some people advice to do exactly this).

I'm going this way for years and I'm totally fine with that. The procedure is the following:
 I am downloading googletest from github. The project itself is coming with CMakeFiles, where is normally no need to modify them. I run cmake and build them in visual studio in isolation. After that I just link my Project against gmock and copy the dlls into my build folder. and done :)!